# Why is it impossible to move a variable to another std::thread

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, c++11, move

What is the reason that you can't move an object to another `std::thread`? There are situations where it could be useful. For example:

You create a loop that accepts incoming socket connections. It would be nice to move incoming connections to another thread that will handle the connections. You don't need the connection anymore in the accept loop. So why should you create a pointer?

A small test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Pointertest
{
public:
    Pointertest() {cout << "Constructor";}
    Pointertest(Pointertest &pointertest) {cout << "Copy";}
    Pointertest(Pointertest &&pointertest) {cout << "Move";}
    ~Pointertest() {cout << "Destruct";}
};

void foo(Pointertest &&pointertest)
{

}

int main()
{
    Pointertest pointertest;

    foo(std::move(pointertest)); //Works
    thread test(foo,std::move(pointertest)); //**cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Pointertest' to 'Pointertest &&'**
}
```

Comment: A practical way to achieve what you want is to use `std::thread test([](Pointertest& p) { foo(std::move(p)); }, std::ref(pointertest));` as `std::ref` is the policy tool to ask for reference semantics where otherwise value semantics are used. There is no policy for 'pass in reference, restore as rvalue', hence the need for the lambda expression to do such a restore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `std::thread` constructor has to treat the arguments you give it somewhat differently from most forwarding functions.

The reason for this is due to questions of when the thread actually gets started. If the part of the function invocation that actually created the function argument gets run long after the `thread` object is created (which is entirely legal behavior), then the object that needs to be moved from may have long since been destroyed.

Just consider an altered version of your code:

```
std::thread some_func()
{
    Pointertest pointertest;

    thread test(foo,std::move(pointertest));
    return test;
}
```

This is perfectly valid (the thread will be moved out of the function). However, there's a big problem. `foo` may not have been called yet. And since `foo` takes its parameter by *reference*, it now has a reference to a stack variable that *has been destroyed*.

That's bad. But even if `foo` took its parameter by value, it would change nothing. Because the actual movement into that parameter doesn't happen until some indeterminate time after the thread has been started. The attempt to move into the parameter will still use an rvalue reference to a stack variable that has been destroyed. Which again is bad.

Therefore, `std::thread` constructor does something different. It copy/moves the arguments you give it into internal storage (this is done on the current thread). Then it uses those values as arguments for the actual function call (this is done on the new thread).

According to the standard, the thread constructor should treat pass these internal variables to your functions as *temporaries*. The standard specifically states `INVOKE (DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`, where the `DECAY_COPY` stuff happens on the original thread, while the `INVOKE` part happens on the new thread.

So it seems like your `thread` implementation isn't able to forward the non-copyable parameters through correctly. You *should* be able to pass a non-copyable type; the arguments are only required to be `MoveConstructible`.

So this would appear to be a bug in your implementation.

Comment: `Therefore, std::thread constructor does something different. It copy/moves the arguments you give it into internal storage (this is done on the current thread). Then it uses those values as arguments for the actual function call (this is done on the new thread).` --> So if I got you right, there will be always two copy/move operations for copyable/movable objects that are passed as an arguments to an `std::thread` ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham: That's not at all what I said. There is one copy/move into the `thread`. Whether calling your thread function requires an additional copy/move is *entirely* up to how you define your thread function.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If so, in case I defined the thread's function with a r-value reference argument (for instance, `void workerThreadFunc(MyObj&& obj)`), where `MyObj` is `move`-able, I should expect than to see additional (second) `move` takes place ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. Fixing the signature of your copy constructor makes it work for me:

```
class Pointertest
{
public:
    Pointertest() {cout << "Constructor";}
    Pointertest(Pointertest const& pointertest) {cout << "Copy";}
//                          ^^^^^^
    Pointertest(Pointertest &&pointertest) {cout << "Move";}
    ~Pointertest() {cout << "Destruct";}
};
```

Also, do not forget to join your thread (or detach from it) before your `thread` object goes out of scope:

```
int main()
{
    Pointertest pointertest;
    thread test(foo, std::move(pointertest));

    test.join();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: I don't want to copy the object; I only want to move it. The destructor can’t be called. I get the same error with your correction.

Comment: @Ordo: "movement" doesn't mean the destructor never gets called. When you move from an object, you're supposed to leave it in a state that is still *functional* (so that it's destructor works). But you've taken all of the important bits from it. Every constructor will still be followed by a destructor eventually; movement doesn't prevent that.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Is it then possible to detect if it is a move? The destructor isn’t called when I move an object to another function.

Comment: @Andy Prowl, I made a screenshot where you can see that I get the same error with your correction: http://postimg.org/image/mmozj68jb/

Comment: @Ordo: That's strange. Perhaps try defining `foo()` as `void foo(Pointertest pointertest)` rather than `void foo(Pointertest&& pointertest)`?

Comment: @Andy Prowl The copy constructor gets called when I do that. The move constructor also gets called but I don’t want a copy call. When I remove the thread part and do a normal function call with those “&&”, then only the move constructor gets called. You also can't compile when you make the copy constructor private.

Comment: @Ordo: Perhaps that is an issue with your compiler then (or most likely with the implementation of the standard library that comes with it), I am trying with GCC 4.7.2 and fixing the signature of the copy constructor is enough to make it compile and run (with the addition of joining the thread, as shown, otherwise an exception is thrown)